# How do I highlight cells in column A that match text in column B?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I'm looking for duplicates. I am trying to highlight all the cells in column A that match text in column B. Cells in column A can be repeated, but B will always have unique text in each cell.

[image: Please see image.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy route, highlight both columns and click (if you don't mind highlighting column B as well).

[image]

Otherwise you could also define a conditional formatting based on a custom formula along these lines:

```
=COUNTIF($B$1:$B$10,A1)>0
```